ROR + ENV Variables vs RedisDB Value
In my current ROR application, I'm using both ENV variables and RedisDB variables as well.
For a single change in ENV variables, I have to restart all servers; by this, lots of jobs fail (dirty exit).
Thinking to switch all ENV variables to RedisDB variables.
Question is WHY?

Is data fetching from RedisDB faster than ENV variables?
Is memory consumption greater in ENV or RedisDB?

Unable to measure statistical data to prove which one is better.

You're doing an apples to oranges comparison here. They are completely different things which serve very different purposes. The only actual resemblance is that both are simple key value structures.
Enviromental variables are variables which are set by the operating system, shell or when invoking the process (or from a file by tools like DotEnv). They are typically used to tell programs things about the environment which they are operating in (thus the name).
In general they should be treated as immutable inputs by the program and configuration which is known at boot time. This is a concept that is built into most operating systems and programming languages.
Redis is an in-memory storage that can be used as key-value database, cache or message broker between programs (and many more things). Unlike ENV variables Redis is a read and write storage.

Is data fetching from RedisDB faster than ENV variables?

It's completely irrelevant as they have different uses. The difference in performance is extremely negible as both are just reading from memory. Redis will have slightly more overhead as you're communicating with a different process.

Is memory consumption greater in ENV or RedisDB?

If memory consumption is an issue you probably shouldn't be memory based storage.

Unable to measure statistical data to prove which one is better. Please suggest

Read up on the two concepts and stop using a screwdriver to beat a nail in.
